# Getting from Chaiyi THSR station to Chiayi City

Tags: public-transport, transportation, taiwan, chiayi

What's the optimal way to get from Chaiyi THSR station to Chiayi City by public transportation? According to Google Maps, there is bus 7211, but it takes almost 2 hours to travel only 15 km (I don't know how accurate this information is). Also, do buses accept Easy Card?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is public transport available, as you mentioned. Bus route 7211 goes direct from central Chiayi and the TRA station to the HSR station in roughly 20-30 minutes - I really don't know why Google Maps is reporting this as a journey time of nearly 2 hours. There was also previously the 7212 route, but it looks like that's been withdrawn since the last time I was over.

For passengers travelling to the HSR station the journey is also free as far as I'm aware, but the last time I took the HSR was in 2014, so double-check - my subsequent journeys from Taipei have been via car. This [Tripadvisor thread](https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/ShowTopic-g1433864-i25525-k10423740-Free_shuttle_bus_from_Chiayi_HSR_to_Chiayi_train_station-Chiayi_County.html) seems to suggest that the journey is still free for HSR ticket holders and NT$48 for those without a ticket.

Chiayi buses do accept EasyCard for short journeys. For longer journeys (i.e. to Alishan National Park) separate tickets need to be bought.

Source: My grandparents-in-law live in Chiayi.

Comment: Do you think it would be easier to take Tze-Chiang (rather than THSR) when traveling from Chiayi to Kaohsiung? Assuming that I will live near the Chiayi Station, it looks like it would be no slower to take the regular train as opposed to taking bus 7211 and then taking THSR.

Comment: Unfortunately I've not been that far south via the west coast before, so I can't really say. I'd imagine taking a TRA service would be substantially cheaper though compared to HSR.

Comment: Actually TRA (Tze-Chiang Limited Express) is only NT$83 ($245 vs. $328) cheaper than HSR (if you buy HSR tickets through Klook). Do you happen to know if TRA Chiayi Station is accessible on foot from "downtown" Chiayi (e.g. from Doujiang Zhi Breakfast Restaurant)? According to Google Maps (probably it's outdated), there is/was some construction and it's not immediately obvious from the Streets View whether it's easy to go to the TRA station from the "downtown".

Comment: @user77409 Not sure if we're thinking of the same place (and I'm not that familiar with "downtown" west of Wenhua Park), but looking at Google Maps the TRA station is only a few minutes walk from Doujang Zhi, north on Ren'Ai Road.

Comment: When I boarded this bus, the driver gave me (and other passengers) some kind of card and then took it back when I got off the bus. Do you happen to know what it was for?

Comment: @user77409 I wouldn't know without seeing unfortunately, I don't remember anything like that last time I went up to Alishan (2016)