# Going to Fenqihu vs. Alishan

Tags: taiwan, mountains

This is sort of a continuation of [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/137497/getting-from-chiayi-to-alishan-through-fenqihu-on-a-sunday/).

Is there much more to see in Alishan compared to Fenqihu? I assume one of the main reasons tourists go to Alishan is to see the sunrise and also to hike. Assuming I will not see the sunrise and will go to Fenqihu, are there other reasons making the trip to Alishan worthwhile? As far as I understand, there are good hiking trails in Fenqihu as well. Are the ones in Alishan significantly better? Or is there something else unique to do in Alishan as opposed to Fenqihu? (One unique reason to visit Fenqihu that I can think of is their lunch boxes; but what about Alishan?)

Comment: I'm not asking to "construct travel and tour itineraries", I'm asking about the difference between Alishan and Fenqihu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trails at Alishan are completely different than those in Fenqihu. Which ones you prefer is a matter of taste but I saw both in 2017 and definitely would not miss the ones at Alishan.

Fenqihu trails are wilder and less obvious than those at Alishan that are more *manicured* in a sense. Think of it like a giant city park with a mountain in the middle. The trails at Alishan are impeccably maintained with wooden paths and stairs, facilities along the way and many interesting stops, including various temples and gardens. It also gets quite crowded there, the most I have seen at a National Park in Taiwan.

On the other hand, around Fenqihu, the trails are much less visited and you can be alone much more easily. While there are some landscaped paths, most of them are just a narrowly cleared paths. There are a few sights of note but much fewer than at Alishan. Do get your food at Fenquihu though, it is really good. Mind that things close quite early there.

Comment: Agreed, Alishan does tend to get stupidly busy at times, especially around the central shops/food area near the entrance, though the further you venture out the quieter it is. The paths are indeed very well maintained, I enjoyed walking along the old abandoned railway line towards the (if I recall correctly) 1000-year-old tree. It really is a choice of busy but well-maintained vs. quiet and off the beaten track.