# Public transportation to Qishan and Meinong from Kaohsiung

Tags: public-transport, buses, taiwan, kaohsiung

For a day trip to Qishan (for the sake of specificity, to Qishan Old Street) and Meinong (Meinong Night Market, again for specificity) from Kaohsiung (e.g. from Central Park), in which order should I visit those places to minimize the transit time (assuming I will use public transportation)? Are there any specific bus routes that I should/should not use for this itinerary (I'm not familiar with Kaohsiung bus system; some of them might be "express" buses or something like that).

I can't trust Google Maps on that because it says that red line + bus E25 to Meinong would take 3h 37min, which I don't think is true (according to the answer [here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/135463/getting-from-chaiyi-thsr-station-to-chiayi-city)). Similarly, Google Maps claim that it takes 1h 38min to get from Meinong to Qishan by bus E25. How much time does it take in practice to get from Kaohsiung to Qishan or Meinong and to travel between Qishan Old Street and Meinong Night Market?